# How to I add offset to datetime in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to add whatever's in the offset the variable `originalDate` parameter passed to `DAYFORMAT` template.

Here's the XML:

```
<StartDate xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
  <b:DateTime>2020-10-27T23:00:00Z</b:DateTime>
  <b:OffsetMinutes>60</b:OffsetMinutes>
</StartDate>
```

This is my code which formats the date but I'm not sure how I can add offset minutes to the DateTime?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="StartDate">
    <date>
        <display>
            <xsl:call-template name='DAYFORMAT'>
                <xsl:with-param name="originalDate" select="node()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </display>
    </date>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="DAYFORMAT">
    <!-- Takes Original Date in 2017-01-01 format, and converts to e.g. Wed -->
    <xsl:param name="originalDate"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($originalDate,9,2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($originalDate,6,2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($originalDate,1,4)"/>
    <!-- eg. 10 Jan 2017 -->
    <xsl:variable name="Y">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month &lt; 3">
                <xsl:value-of select="$year - 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$year + 0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$Y mod 100"/>
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="floor($Y div 100)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="$day+0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month &lt; 3">
                <xsl:value-of select="$month + 12"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$month + 0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="w" select="($d + floor(($m + 1) * 2.6) + $y + floor($y div 4) + floor($c div 4) - $c * 2 - 1) mod 7"/>
    <xsl:variable name="www">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 0">Sun</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 1">Mon</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 2">Tue</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 3">Wed</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 4">Thu</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 5">Fri</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$w = 6">Sat</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="monthName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$month=01">January</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=02">February</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=03">March</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=04">April</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=05">May</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=06">June</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=07">July</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=08">August</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=09">September</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=10">October</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=11">November</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$month=12">December</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$www"/>
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$monthName"/>
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is the desired result:

```
<Display>Sat 28 November</Display>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you really limited to XSLT 1.0? This is much easier if your processor supports XSLT 2.0+.

Comment: michael.hor257k, I can use 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, this could be as simple as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs b">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="StartDate">
    <xsl:variable name="adjusted-dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(b:DateTime) + b:OffsetMinutes * xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')"/>
    <Display>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($adjusted-dateTime, '[FNn,*-3] [D] [MNn]')"/>
    </Display>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbpGC