# Xslt 1.0 : Adding hours (integer) to time stamp

Tags: datetime, timestamp, xslt-1.0

I am struggeling to add 2 hours to a time stamp. It is not a possibility to upgrade to XSLT version 2.0 unformatunately.

08:40:20

Desired output:

10:40:20

Comment: I suppose the issue will be if your org-time is like 23:40:20
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64224318/3710053

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="Time">
    <DesiredTime>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ':') + 2" />
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ':')" />
    </DesiredTime>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want it to roll back to 0 after midnight, then do:

```
         <xsl:value-of select="(substring-before(., ':') + 2) mod 24" />
```

and if you want a leading zero then wrap it in `format-number()`.